# How to create my own UIAlertController in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have graphic that I would like to create as a UIAlertController? Can I create a xib and then call that file to present it? What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alert is nothing but a presented view controller. So make your own view controller and call `present`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: But how can I make the view controller as small as an alert? Won't presenting a view controller show the whole thing?

Comment: Well, that's the lovely thing about a presented view controller. The size and position of the view are completely up to you. You can even add a background "dimming" if you like! Plus you can add an animation so it appears just the way an alert view would. See my https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 for an example.

Comment: Awesome! That gives a ton of clarity thank you.

Comment: So I see your project, how can I add a curve in a XIB file?

Comment: Hey, we've kind of veered off topic. :) If you have a new question, ask it as a New Question. Thanks!

Comment: Very true. Will do

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subclass of UIView and its corresponding Xib.
Just create an instance whenever you need to use it and just add it as a subview.
And on the tap of close button just remove it.

Make sure that you create a method in the UIView subclass, which accepts the text, and the button titles, and call the method whenever you are adding it.
So you can add dynamic button titles or texts if the same popup is being used in multiple places in your application.